# Javascript confirm popup box opening too late

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a confirm action Javascript popup box that is supposed to open when the user clicks an action button in a gridview. My problem is that the popup box doesn't open until after the entire sub's code has executed and the variable that needs to have a value assigned doesn't get the value assigned until it's too late. How can I get the popup to open and allow the user to populate the DelUserConfirm variable before the sub ends? Thanks in advance for the help! My code is as follows:

Sub Gridview_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)

```
    Dim currentcommand As String = e.CommandName
    Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
    Dim cell As GridViewRow = grdUsers.Rows(index)
    Dim currUserID As String = grdUsers.Rows(index).Cells(0).Text

    If e.CommandName = "DelUser" Then

        Dim DelUserConfirm As String = Request.Form("confirm_value")

        If (Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("alert")) Then

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(action), _
                "alert", "Confirm()", True)

        End If

        If DelUserConfirm = "Yes" Then

            cmd.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME = '" + currUserID + "'"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
            dtUsers.Rows(index).Delete()
            grdUsers.DataSource = dtUsers
            grdUsers.DataBind()

        End If

        Exit Sub

    End If

    If e.CommandName = "EditUser" Then

        Session("EditUserPerms") = dtUsers(index)
        Session("UserPerms") = dtUserPerms
        Response.Redirect("AddEditUser.aspx")

    End If

End Sub
```

Adding the webform code...

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="UserAdmin.aspx.vb" Inherits="_3rd_party_data_reporting_tool.UserAdmin" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function Confirm() {
var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
confirm_value.type = "hidden";
confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete this user?")) {
confirm_value.value = "Yes";
} else {
confirm_value.value = "No";
}
document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
}
</script>
<body>
<form id="UserAdmin" runat="server">
<asp:Image ID="imgTRLogo" runat="server" Height="120px" ImageUrl="~/TR_Logo.bmp" Width="120px" style="z-index: 1; left: 5px; top: 5px; position: absolute" />
<asp:Label ID="lblTitle1" runat="server" Text="CA - Global Product Operations" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial Black" Font-Size="XX-Large" style="z-index: 1; left: 170px; top: 20px; position: absolute"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblTitle2" runat="server" Text="Productivity Tools" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial Black" Font-Size="XX-Large" style="z-index: 1; left: 282px; top: 60px; position: absolute"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblTitle3" runat="server" Text="User Administration Panel" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial Black" Font-Size="Large" style="z-index: 1; left: 312px; top: 135px; position: absolute"></asp:Label>
<asp:GridView ID="grdUsers" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" autogeneratecolumns="false" style="z-index: 1; left: 28px; top: 184px; position: absolute; height: 144px; width: 731px" OnRowCommand="Gridview_RowCommand" >
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="USER_NAME" HeaderText="User ID"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="PW" HeaderText="Password"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="FIRST_NAME" HeaderText="First Name"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="LAST_NAME" HeaderText="Last Name"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="EMAIL" HeaderText="E-mail Address"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="SAFE_ID" HeaderText="SAFE ID"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="THIRDPTYRPT" HeaderText="3rd Party Report"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="EDTK" HeaderText="eDTK Tool"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="ADMIN" HeaderText="Admin"/>
<asp:buttonfield ButtonType="Button" CommandName="EditUser" HeaderText="Edit User?" Text="Edit" />
<asp:buttonfield ButtonType="Button" CommandName="DelUser" HeaderText="Delete User?" Text="Delete" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="cmdAddNewUser" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 28px; top: 149px; position: absolute; width: 132px" Text="Add New User" />
<asp:Button ID="cmdExit" runat="server" style="position: absolute; top: 22px; left: 729px; height: 45px; width: 54px" Text="Exit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide your webform code? How is your confirm box?

Comment: Can you put an OnClientClick="" tag on the button itself? Otherwise, RegisterStartupScript just loads the javascript after the rest of the page.

Comment: You do realize that the .NET code runs on the server and the confirm runs on the client and there is no connection between the two until the user submits a form or clicks a link.

Comment: Use this on page load - ASPControlID.Attributes["onClick"] = "return confirm('Are you sure?');"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change `ButtonField` to  `TemplateField`.

[Delete Confirmation for Delete ButtonField, TemplateField and CommandField in a GridView](http://www.dotnetspeaks.net/post/Delete-Confirmation-for-Delete-ButtonField-TemplateField-and-CommandField-in-a-GridView.aspx)

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdUsers" runat="server" ... >
<Columns>
    ...
   <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
         CommandName="DelUser" 
         OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');" 
         Text="Delete" />
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```